# Inline for loop

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

I'm trying to learn neat pythonic ways of doing things, and was wondering why my for loop cannot be refactored this way:

```
q  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vm = [-1, -1, -1, -1]

for v in vm:
    if v in q:
        p.append(q.index(v))
    else:
        p.append(99999)

vm[p.index(max(p))] = i
```

I tried replacing the for loop with:

```
[p.append(q.index(v)) if v in q else p.append(99999) for v in vm]
```

But it doesn't work. The `for v in vm:` loop evicts numbers from `vm` based on when they come next in `q`.

Comment: You may want to use -1 instead of 99999 for a flagging an inexistent value (so it would work even for a list with 99999+ elements)

Comment: you list comprehsnsion will work but it will return lists of None too

Comment: I used 99999 instead of -1 because later I ran a max(p) and nonexistent values need to be selected.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

What you are using is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python, not an inline for-loop (even though it is similar to one). You would write your loop as a list comprehension like so:

```
p = [q.index(v) if v in q else 99999 for v in vm]
```

When using a list comprehension, you do not call `list.append` because the list is being constructed from the comprehension itself.  Each item in the list will be what is returned by the expression on the left of the `for` keyword, which in this case is `q.index(v) if v in q else 99999`.  Incidentially, if you do use `list.append` inside a comprehension, then you will get a list of `None` values because that is what the `append` method always returns.

Comment: Thanks man, awesome!  +internets for answering in less than a minute.

Answer (score 13):

your list comprehension will work but will return list of None, because append returns None:

demo:

```
>>> a = []
>>> [a.append(x) for x in range(10)]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

better way to use it like this:

```
>>> a = [x for x in range(10)]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) keeping the ind/index of the elements is in vm, if you make `vm` a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) you will also have `0(1)` lookups:

```
vm = {-1, -1, -1, -1}

print([ind if q in vm else 9999 for ind,ele in enumerate(vm) ])
```

Comment: Cool fancy syntax, thanks for sharing this looks very useful!

Answer (score 3):

```
q  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
vm = [-1, -1, -1, -1,1,2,3,1]

p = []
for v in vm:
    if v in q:
        p.append(q.index(v))
    else:
        p.append(99999)

print p
p = [q.index(v) if v in q else 99999 for v in vm]
print p
```

Output:

```
[99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 0, 1, 2, 0]
[99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Instead of using `append()` in the list comprehension you can reference the p as direct output, and use `q.index(v)` and `99999` in the LC.

Not sure if this is intentional but note that `q.index(v)` will find just the first occurrence of `v`, even tho you have several in `q`. If you want to get the index of all `v` in `q`, consider using a `enumerator` and a list of already visited `indexes`

Something in those lines(pseudo-code):

```
visited = []
for i, v in enumerator(vm):
   if i not in visited:
       p.append(q.index(v))
   else:
       p.append(q.index(v,max(visited))) # this line should only check for v in q after the index of max(visited)
   visited.append(i)
```