# The result of inline and usual for loops are different

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a tree from which I want to return its children as a list through a function. In this function, I needed to iterate over a list of strings. At first I did it by using the inline *for loop*

```
    def get_children(root):
        
        Data = [ ]
        Data.append( root.data )
        
        for child in root.children:
              Data.append( elem for elem in get_children(child) )
        return Data
```

However, I got the following strange result:

```
['Electronics', <generator object get_children.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7fb3a081a3c0>, <generator object get_children.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7fb3a081a7b0>, <generator object get_children.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7fb3a081a9e0>]
```

Then, I changed the inline *for loop* into a typical one and the problem is resolved, i.e.,

```
   for elem in get_children(child):
        Data.append( elem )
```

I was wondering if you could help me understand why this happened. I've read a similar post about [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411631/inline-for-loop), however, I'm still confused trying to understand the difference here.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehensions

Comment: There's no such thing as an "inline for loop". What you have is a generator expression, which produces an object that can be iterated over lazily.

Comment: If anything, you would want `Data.append(elem) for elem in get_children(child)` anyway (but that's not going to do what you think it would). Just use `Data.extend(get_children(child))`.

Comment: I dont know why but i am getting an `no attribute` error at `data.append(root.data)` and aswell as on for child in `root.children`

Comment: I dont know why but i am getting an `no attribute` error at `data.append(root.data)` and aswell as on for child in `root.children`

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't wrap your list comprehension with [], the return value of it is a generator expression (which generates the list you made).
You can fix this by simply wrapping the expression with []

Comment: Thank you! It resolved the issue but it does not  give the desired result. In fact it returns a list of lists instead of a list. So, the result is still different with that of the typical for loop.

Comment: @BoofKoor , see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 2):

you used Generator expressions instead of list comprehension
Generator Expressions are somewhat similar to list comprehensions, but the former doesn’t construct list object.
Instead of creating a list and keeping the whole sequence in the memory the generator generates the next element in demand.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here at `Data.append( elem for elem in get_children(child))`, you haven't wrapped the list comprehension. So the solution is `Data.append([elem for elem in get_children(child)])` to just add `[` at start and `]` at end of  list comprehension.

I think yo are trying to get all child of the root, well here's solution from [Getting every child widget of a Tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7290709/18002691)

```
root.winfo_children()
```

You can use this instead of `for-loop`, as this would provide you with every children of root window.