# Parse int to date in a list of dictionaries

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My list:

```
var list = [{"id": 1, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 2, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 3, "date": 1649368800000}]
```

Desired output:

```
var list = [{"id": 1, "date": 01.01.2022}, {"id": 2, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 3, "date": 01.01.2022}]
```

How can I effectively iterate through my list and parse my int values in "date" to a human readable date format?

For the start I tried to just print the date values..

```
var list_of_values = [a_dict["date"] for a_dict in list]
```

but failed with **Parsing error: ',' expected**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing [python](/questions/tagged/python) with [javacript](/questions/tagged/javacript).

That short-for loop is [the python way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411631/inline-for-loop)

---

Since you tagged this [javacript](/questions/tagged/javacript), I'd recommend [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`new Date()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript):

---

###### Parsed to date format

```js
var list = [{"id": 1, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 2, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 3, "date": 1649368800000}];

list.forEach(o => o.date = new Date(o.date));

console.log(list);
```

###### Parsed to dd.mm.yyyy

```js
var list = [{"id": 1, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 2, "date": 1649368800000}, {"id": 3, "date": 1649368800000}];

list.forEach(o => {
  const d = new Date(o.date);
  o.date = `${d.getDate()}.${d.getMonth() + 1}.${d.getFullYear()}`
});

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Hi 0stone0, thank you! You are correct. I mixed it up. Thank you for extracting the dates. How can I manipulate my original date with your .map function, so that the int values are replaced with the date values?

Comment: What do you mean by 'date values'? Please click the link of the `new Date`, you can add a format like you want.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: With your code, I receive the list of the parsed dates. But my original data "list" is still untouched. I want to replace the values inside "list" and not extract the dates

Comment: Ahh, so you want `list` to become an array with the 3 unix timestamps?

Comment: Yes. The original list (array of dictionaries) should remain the same with the exception of the parsed dates! :) (Thank you for your time btw)

Comment: please see my edit, i think you want something like this; i've used `foreach` instead off map since you don't needd a single return

Comment: Hi again, I think this piece of code will convert my list of dictionaries to a list with only the converted date and nothing else. My console output is like [Fri Apr 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit),Fri Apr 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit),Fri Apr 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit),Fri Apr 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit),Fri Apr 08 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)] now, without the single dictionaries

Comment: Yea I was to fast, did you see my latest edit with `foreach`?

Comment: I have added my desired output in my thread, if its still unclear